# Rewording the 'close'-dialog

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is the status quo of the close dialog:

### This thread is not about the *chances* to get a change done, but about whether we *want* to change the dialog.

> Why should this question be closed?
>
> - exact duplicate
>   This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with
>   another identical question.
> - off topic
>   Questions on German Language and Usage - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate to German language, within the scope
>   defined in the faq.
> - not constructive
>   This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or
>   specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate,
>   arguments, polling, or extended discussion.
> - not a real question
>   It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or
>   rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.
> - too localized
>   This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific
>   moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not
>   generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Most points are ok, but the whole thing is obviously imported from a different site without adapting it.

I suggest new suggestions, referring to one point (1-5) per answer, but maybe more answers per point, to vote on new formulations.

I don't expect suggestions for *1. exact duplicate* , *2. off topic*, "4. not a real question", but if you have an issue, feel free to argue about it.

"Too localized" is a bit problematic: I guess 50% of our questions are too localized (How would you translate X in situation Y), but I guess this is by design.

So it is mostly the `not constructive` point, but it is good to have some context here, and to see, what is covered from the other paragraphs.

Please provide a paragraph which shall replace the current one and a visually distinctive reasoning, to defend your suggestion, or a defense for the old solution.

I beg for answers in two languages.

---

### Das Thema ist nicht, ob man eine Änderung realisieren kann, sondern ob wir eine Änderung wollen.

Oben sieht man den Status quo des `close`-Dialogs, zum Schließen von Fragen.

Die meisten Punkte sind ok, auch wenn man sieht, dass der Dialog ohne Anpassung von einer anderen Seite übernommen wurde. Ich schlage vor Vorschläge zu machen, wie dieser verbessert werden soll, aber immer nur einen Punkt pro Posting zu behandeln, damit diese getrennt bewertet werden können. Mehrere Postings zu einem Punkt sind natürlich willkommen.

Für *1. exact duplicate* , *2. off topic* und  *4. not a real question*, sehe ich eigentlich keine Änderungsbedarf. "Too localized" sind bei uns ohnehin etwa 50% der Fragen, die dem Muster "Wie übersetze ich X, wenn ich in Situation Y die Nuance Z ausdrücken will" entsprechen, aber eine Verbesserungsmöglichkeit dafür sehe ich nicht. Aber fühlt Euch frei das anders zu sehen.

Es geht also hauptsächlich um den Punkt *3. not constructive*, aber es ist gut diesen im Kontext zu sehen, um zu wissen, was von anderen Punkten abgehandelt wird.

Bitte einen deutlich hervorgehobenen Absatz mit der Neufassung beitragen und einer Begründung wieso, oder ein Pladoyer für den derzeitigen Stand.

Ich bitte um zweisprachige Antworten.

Comment: No. He is arguing against the possibility to realize the feature, not whether he would prefer it or not. But I'm not interested in the probability to realize it, but if the community thinks it is a necessity. Did you notice my edits? The debate below his post?

Comment: I didn't see the debate below his post until he'd undeleted it. I assure you that Alenanno's answer is perfectly appropriate answer to your feature request, since it's explaining why it's not going to happen.

Comment: Can't you see that it is not about whether it is going to happen, but what we want? Because you would like to discusss his question too, but not mine? You like to tell me, that I don't know what my question is?

Comment: @userunknown I also added an edit where I wrote my opinion about your proposal.

Comment: You received upvotes for your off topic posting, and the parts which are off topic are still present. I can't remove my requests from the comments so long. It makes the answer noisy and useless, if the real part is somehow appended at the end. What shall the people vote on?

Comment: I’m closing this question as off-topic because it does not apply anymore due to general changes in the close dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just remove close-reasons like that, I think. I guess that the only situations that allow you to change a close-reason is done when there is an actual reason for it.

For example, take the "General Reference". It's not there by default, but only added when on the site there are many questions that can be answered with a standard resource that was easy to check for the OP.

The changes are never done without an actual reason behind them. There have been many proposals about this issue, but they have been all rejected, I guess. Check the meta question *"[I propose changing the term “closed” out for… something else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70061/176533)"* on MSO.

If you — or someone else — want to read more about those two reasons you mentioned, Joel gave a [good explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87415/176533) about what is a *too localized* question, while Robert wrote a blog post about the "not constructive" close reason, giving some guidelines about *"[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)"* questions.

**Edit**: I want to add my opinion about the proposals.

If you think there are many questions that are too simple and that can be looked up in dictionaries, for example (I suppose you need to prove it somehow) then you can ask to implement the "General Reference" close reason. If there are really many posts like this, I agree to add it. I've seen it on EL&U and it works there, so if you really think there is a need for it, I think it'd be reasonable. In such a case, I suggest we define what is considered General Reference and what is not.

On the other hand, I disagree about removing/changing the "Not constructive" (which is quite different from the "General Reference" one) or any of the other reasons. They all still serve their purpose.

Comment: You don't answer my question. Please make a comment out of it. This is not a comment on the validness of your expression - it's just not an answer for my question.

Comment: @userunknown (re-pasting because I made a mistake) You proposed to reword it, and I simply said that you can't do it (using MSO as a reference, I didn't decide it). If you really believe you should, you can ask an SE Team Member and if they agree, they'll implement it for you. You can also ask on MSO, and see what they answer. I think that's the place to ask...

Comment: If you want to transport the information, that it is impossible, your answer should be a comment. I'm talking about what *should* be done, not what *could* be done. I don't need to ask anybody, if we don't agree that something should be done. Of course I could first ask what could be done, have a long discussion on Meta, and later realize, that I'm the only one in favor to change anything. If my thread reminds you of the possibility to discuss a similar topic, please open a new discussion, I won't miss it. But don't hijack my thread to post different issues. I don't want to flag your post.

Comment: @userunknown Why should it be a comment? I am not saying you can't discuss about this, that would not be in my power and it certainly is not my intention. You can discuss about it and everybody can post an answer or a comment. What I was underlining is that you should ask someone (SE Team) and usually they refuse if there isn't a *strong* reason (I know from experience from another meta question). If you have a strong reason, they might accept to add something.

Comment: It's not about *me* having a strong reason. Either we as a community want to change this dialog, or not. If I don't find a majority for my position, I will drop it. If you want to change the dialog, but don't believe it is possible, vote for me. If you don't want to change it, defend the status quo, and vote against my idea. But don't discuss the possibility to change it in the answers of my thread, please!

Comment: @userunknown I also added a part about your proposals.

Comment: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Btw. I didn't suggest to remove 'too localized'.

Comment: @userunknown Why "Lorem ipsum"? Anyway, my bad, I'll correct that.

Comment: Yes - I appended the part to topic at the end. Do you see how the discussion is getting much too long? I can't remove my comments, while the misleading part is still present. And IMHO it is bad style if you try to save the reputations from the old answer to the new one, because you earned it for the comment part. I have meanwhile flagged your text as off topic. I would like to process this discussion in chat, but it does not finish loading on my side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2468/discussion-between-alenanno-and-user-unknown)

Answer (score -1):

> - not constructive
>     This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We
>     expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific
>     expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate,
>     arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Kritik am Status quo:

Mit "involve facts" haben wir wenig am Hut. Was für Referenzen sind gemeint? Welche spezifische Expertise?

Und Meinungen sind bei Sprachfragen selten zu vermeiden, und Debatten entspinnen sich regelmäßig an Kleinigkeiten - womöglich zu oft, aber sicher ist das nicht ganz vermeidbar.

Ich meine der Punkt kann ganz weg, aber sollte ersetzt werden mit dem, was wir tatsächlich oft haben: Trivialen Übersetzungsanfragen.

Vorschlag:

> - trivial translation request
>     This question is a trivial translation
>     request which can be answered by a simple online-dictionary search,
>     which can be found in our FAQ.

Natürlich bedarf die FAQ dann eine entsprechende Überarbeitung und Aufnahme des Links zur Liste mit entsprechenden Angeboten. Das Wort FAQ sollte dann, wenn die Schließung vorgenommen wird, mit der FAQ verlinkt sein.

---

Critic about the satus quo:

*Involve facts, references or specific expertise* look like aliens for our site.

Opinions are very often involved and not always avoidable. For a language side, it is normal to have different opinons on what is appropriate, what is used, what is understand, what fits best in questions of translations.

Drop that rule, but replace it with something which is needed often - the trivial translation request.

(Suggestion see german section).

Of course the FAQ needs an update in that direction, and a link to the list of online dictionary services. When a question is closed, the link to the FAQ should automatically be provided.

Comment: On [french.se] we use “too localized” for questions best looked up in a dictionary, because the next person with the same question won't be helped by having the answer on SE in addition to a dictionary. I don't see how “facts, references or specific expertise” is alien on a language site.